# How to add class name programmatically to views field in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I'm developing a drupal website and I'm using views module to create a block. I'm displaying a view as fields. In my custom module I want to add class name to one view's field if one other field's value is 0.

How to do this?

**EDIT***

I found solution to my problem. See my answer below. I didn't mark it as accepted because it actually don't answer my original question how to add the class name *programmatically.* I'm still interested to know how to do it programmatically so if someone has good answer for me I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to my problem. The solution doesn't require coding or custom module and can be done only with views settings.

First I excluded the field from the display where I wanted the class name be. Then the other field I overwrote like this: `<div id="field1">[field1]</div><div id="field2">[field2]</div>`.

I also overwrote the field2 when its empty and checked the settings that 0 will be also counted  as empty. In the overwrite I added the class name: `<div id="field1" class="something">[field1]</div><div id="field2">[field2]</div>`

Now when the field2 is 0 it will be overwritten and it will display the field1 with class name.